# Innodb, updating thousands of records result in lock timeout

Tags: mysql

there is a big update:

```
UPDATE myBigTable SET x=0;
```

which cant be done, I get SQL Error (1205), Lock wait timeout exceeded. I tried to turn off autocommit, still no result. How to update then?

EDIT: I tried to disable autocommit, still no joy

Comment: Have you considered chunking it? Something like `UPDATE myBigTable SET x=0 WHERE x!=0 LIMIT 10000;` and loop until it's done?

Answer (score 1):

You can try to increase the lockout time period like this:

```
mysql> set innodb_lock_wait_timeout=100
```

where 100 is in seconds.

Or you can try to kill the process which is actually locking your process like:

```
mysql> kill processId;
```

Comment: just increasing the lock timeout is not a solution. way OP performing update should never be done in real time.

Answer (score 0):

> there is a big update:

Are you really sure you want to update all of your table records? What you currently doing doesn't looks correct. You should probably consider using A `where` filter condition and perform update; like `UPDATE myBigTable SET x=0 WHERE id = value;` If you really want to update entire table records then consider using it in batch rather in single go.